# how to remove new line character from csv file's element java

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV File with a column were that column spans to multiple lines. I want to aggregate those multiple lines into one line.

For example

```
1, "asdsdsdsds", "John"
2, "dfdhifdkinf
dfjdfgkdnjgknkdjgndkng
dkfdkjfnjdnf", "Roy"
3, "dfjfdkgjfgn", "Rahul"
```

I want my output to be

```
1, "asdsdsdsds", "John"
2, "dfdhifdkinf dfjdfgkdnjgknkdjgndkng dkfdkjfnjdnf", "Roy"
3, "dfjfdkgjfgn", "Rahul"
```

How should I remove the new line by java.

Comment: Use a proper CSV parser like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @BoristheSpider which function?

Comment: Start reading each character from the CSV file and keep on appending the characters of the file to a `StringBuilder` object if it isn't a `line separator`. If the character is a `line separator`, just ignore it. Finally when the iteration will be done, you'll have a proper CSV in your `StringBuilder` object.

Comment: What do you mean by _which function_? The CSV parsing one. Obviously.

Comment: @AmanAgnihotri You are kidding right?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I am using a proper parser (RFC4180Parser) and it still prints out ugly newlines. What exactly do you mean by "proper"?

Comment: @Justin Di you find any solution or parser that would pretty print it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CSV Reader using OpenCSV as follows:

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(fileName)))));
```

You can read each row using the method csvReader.readNext(). It returns a String array.

```
String [] nextRow = csvReader.readNext();
```

It will handle the new lines in the column.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove end of line character `\n` from your file and then write file to csv file.

```
public static void remove(String[] args) throws Exception {

    CSVReader main = new CSVReader(new FileReader("path to csv file"));
    String [][] look= new String [row][col];

    int line =0;
    String [] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = main.readNext())!=null){

       nextLine[1]=nextLine[1].replaceAll("\n", "");
       look[line]=nextLine; 
       line++;
    }

    BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.csv"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int m=0;m<row;m++) {

      for(int p=0; p<col;p++){
         sb.append(look[m][p]).append(",");
      }
      sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf(","));
      sb.append("\n");
    }

    br.write(sb.toString());
    br.close();
}
```

Comment: can you properly name your variables :)